# asp.net mvc 3 using IsInt() in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, isinteger

I would like to check if my variable is an integer in controller. In view I can easily use isInt() but not in the controller. Do I need to have a special reference to use that method?

Thank you.

Comment: I want to return view with path as argument, but first I need to know if the path is a number or not. In view I can use `Where(x=>x.path.IsInt() == true)`, but in controller I think I need a reference so I can use that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the following namespace you can use it in your controller.

```
using System.Web.Webpages;
```

Depending on your usage you might want to use Int32.TryParse() instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
int result;
if (int.TryParse(x, out result))
{
    // do something with result, which is a "strong" int
}
```